# How to run a react app on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to run the following example:
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-react-example

(ag-grid react example)

But, instead of doing `npm run` I want to run it on tomcat. How to do it?

Comment: Hey can you share your final solution? I am trying to the same to

Answer (score 8):

You can easily deploy any static files on Tomcat. The project you linked does not have a script to build production version of the sample, so what you need to do is:

1. Install **webpack** locally: `npm install -g webpack`
2. Build demo: `webpack --config webpack.config.standard.js --progress --colors --hot --inline` or `webpack --config webpack.config.large.js --progress --colors --hot --inline`. It will create `dist` directory.
3. In Tomcat `webapps` directory create create another directory for your demo `ag-grid`.
4. Copy `index.html` and `dist` to `ag-grid`.
5. Access it on `http://host:port/ag-grid`.

Comment: Getting the following error when trying to do step 2 :path.js:8
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [ 'webpack.config.standard.js', 'webpack.config.large.js' ]

Comment: Sorry, ignore the above comment. My bad!

Comment: So I have this another file demo.jsp, that reads data from some database and convert that data to json, I'm doing the following in my jsp file: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(orderDetailsList1);
<input type="hidden" value='<%out.println(jsonArray);%>' id="jsonArray"/>
Can I read this json data in my ag-grid project? Maybe do : var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
c

Comment: Is it possible to do the above thing?

Comment: I've shown you how to run example in Tomcat - something you asked for. Now you are asking me to do the job for you. I recommend going to ag-grid documentation and learn how to fill grid with data coming from backend.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, I was looking for this answer for a long time :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you're starting from scratch I would recommend using create-react-app instead of custom webpack scripts.

Comment: awesome. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

Execute

```
npm run build
```

This will create the deployable version of your app in the `build` subfolder inside your project tree. All you need now is to copy the `index.html` with its all friends from this folder into your Tomcat directory intended to serve static files. This is the top level in the Tomcat application folder. The standard directory layout documented [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout).

It is also very simple build a real web application (.war) as described [here](http://dmitryli.blogspot.ch/2013/02/serving-static-html-within-war-file.html). Static files just reside on the top level of the archive, you should also configure default pages in WEB-INF/web.xml inside the archive. Such app can be deployed from Tomcat administration console.

Comment: This assumes the application was created with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which is not the case in the example refered to.

Comment: Tried that on Tomcat 9.x; note that you may need to put the 'static' folder, directly under 'webapps' to make it work with no 404 errors.

Comment: Just running npm run build will not make it run on Tomcat. 'npm run build' builds the js app, but it doesn't make it ready for a deploying on a particular web server. There are many variables and moving parts deploying js apps, and how to deploy on Tomcat will depend on many factors..e.g. context folder, version of Tomcat etc.

Comment: The generated js app can be deployed on any server as long as this server can serve the basic HTML/JS content.

Comment: where I put then .env file? I was asked to put it inside conf folder in Tomcat but its outside the project. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redux Counter Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="~/Scripts/frontend/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Even though I did not do this with Tomcat I deployed it with IIS. So you can adapt the method to Tomcat.

1. I created an Empty MVC application with a Default Controller and a Default view to get all the MVC magic that Microsoft provides.
2. I built the React + Redux application with webpack and sent everything into a dist folder that had all the resources needed for the application. Look into how to build a React app with webpack for more details on this.
3. In the script tag that my main view was delivering I set it to point to the dist folder with all the React code.
4. I ran the application through the Visual Studio build process and the React code kicked in when the view was served by IIS.
5. Routing worked as well and Redux dev tools.

DefaultController.cs

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }
```

Default.cshtml

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redux Counter Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="~/Scripts/frontend/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about how to deploy on Apache Tomcat exactly.